# getting file already exist error as code running async

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous

As below code runs async, 2 zip created with same name and when trying to copy destination, getting error saying that,

> The file 'C:\Temp\test_20181024032123496.Zip' already exists.

How to skip this condition? Thanks!

```
private static async Task<bool> GenerateZipFile(FileSystemInfo file1, string zipFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var zip = ZipFile.Open($"{zipFilePath}\\test_{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmmssfff}.Zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file1.FullName, file1.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "skip" it?  Skip it how?  Do you want to overwrite the file anyway?  Or just not process that file?

Comment: That code shouldn't compile, because there's no `await` in the `async` method. Having said that, do you not need an `if (!File.Exists(...))` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to skip processing for file

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about this code. `async` doesn't make something asynchronous, it's just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to await already asynchronous operations. Only *you* know what you want to do with existing files. Overwrite them? Extract a copy? Abort the operation?

Comment: If you want to skip, just check whether the file exists in advance with `File.Exists`

Comment: Why are *two* zip files created with the same name anyway? What are you really trying to do and what kind of application are you building? If it's a desktop application why create *duplicate* files? If it's a web application, why create the same filename instead of using different paths, temporary names etc and sending the file to the client with a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'm not sure if you have the problem with the zip file you're creating or with the file you're adding into the zip file so I'm adding code that checks if either of them exists

```
private static async Task<bool> GenerateZipFile(FileSystemInfo file1, string zipFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        string newZipFilePath = $"{zipFilePath}\\test_{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmmssfff}.Zip"
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newZipFilePath))
        {
            using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(newZipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                if(System.IO.File.Exists(file1.FullName))
                {
                    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file1.FullName, file1.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

This should work, but you should also check which is the one you actually need and only use that one

Comment: Yes, I did same, Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you probably need both checks just to be sure.